# linkedin authorize window with Electron

Tags: electron, linkedin-api

When using the `IN.User.authorize` API from my electron app , I get an error and got a blank page:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Function' of undefined
>       at xdrpc.html?v=1.0.87-1429:901
>       at xdrpc.html?v=1.0.87-1429:1709

Using chrome/FF, everything is ok.

Note that `nodeIntegration` flags has been set to false already. Is there something else I need to configure in order to work ?